# Sustituir cada palabra de una cadena por otra en ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estaba navegando en la web y me tope con algo como esto:

```
console.log('cada palabra sera sustituida por el emoji de pizza'.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' '))
```

Esto funciona perfectamente, lo que no entiendo es como en el `return` `word && ''`  de la función de callback es que convierte la palabra al emoji. si alguien me lo explica se lo agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `.map()` de  Javascript, es un método del objeto `Array`.

Como sabemos un `Array` es una colección enumerable de elementos.

Según la documentación de [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), al aplicar la misma a un `Array`, se hace una llamada a la función `callback` pasada como argumento, para cada elemento (en orden) del `Array`. Esta función `callback` recibe el elemento del `Array` como argumento. Así, por cada elemento se aplicarán operaciones.

Ahora, en el caso de tu pregunta, resulta que se tiene un tipo `string`, al cual se le aplica el método `split()`. Según la documentación de [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), éste método divide un objeto tipo `string` en un `Array` de elementos tipo `stirng` mediante la separación del `string` original en `substrings`. La separación la hará en palabras, ya que a la función `split()` se la ha pasado como argumento el carácter de espacio.

Ahora ya tenemos nuestro `Array` de palabras. Al cual le aplicamos la función `map()`.

Dentro de nuestra función `map`, por cada palabra usaremos la sentencia: `return word &&`

En Javascript, el operador [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) es un operador lógico de `corto-circuito` que regresa uno de los operandos que se están evaluando.

Usualmente, el operador `&&` se utiliza con valores tipo `boolean`, sin embargo, si se usan con valores diferentes al tipo `boolean`, el resultado de la comparación devolverá uno de los valores que se están comparando.

Se le llama operador de cortocircuito, porque si el primer valor o expresión a evaluar es `false` o (devuelve `false`), la segunda expresión no se evalúa y se devuelve sólo el resultado de la primera evaluación. En cambio si la primera evaluación devuelve `true`, se realiza la segunda evaluación y se devuelve el resultado de esta segunda evaluación.

En el caso concreto de tu pregunta, el primer valor a evaluar es `word`. Dado que `word` es un objeto tipo `string`, la evaluación de dicho `string` devuelve `true`. En Javascript existen valores que se consideran [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy), es decir que al evaluarse devuelven `true`.

Como el primer valor devuelve `true`, el motor de Javascript procede a evaluar el segundo valor. En este caso el segundo valor es , que también devuelve `true`.

Ahora, dado que  no es un tipo `boolean`, entonces el operador `&&` devuelve como resultado el valor del segundo elemento, en este caso devuelve .

Por último, el `Array` resultante (mapeado) contiene elementos emoji . Al aplicar el método [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join), a nuestro `Array` de emojis, se unirán todos nuestros elementos, usando como conector el carácter de espacio que hemos pasado como argumento a `join()`.

Es así como cada palabra en el `string` original es reemplazada (mapeada) por .

Espero que esto responda tu duda. Saludos

Comment: esto responde perfectamente a mi duda, gracias

Answer (score 3):

la funcion [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) crea un nuevo arreglo a partir de un callback que se ejecuta para cada elemento del mismo:

```
console.log('cada palabra sera sustituida por el emoji de pizza'.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' '))
```

> ahora bien vamos a desglosar la funcion a codigo mas simple de entender

**ejemplo:**

```js
 string = "cada palabra sera sustituida por    el emoji de pizza";
// creamos un arreglo words utilizando como separador el espacio
words = string.split(' ');
// creamos un arreglo change
change = [];
// hacemos un bucle for
for(let x of words){
// validamos que no este vacia esa posicion
 if(x){
 // agregamos al arreglo 
  change.push('')
 }
}

// volvemos a unir el arreglo con espacio de division
newstring = change.join(' ');
// imprimimos el arreglo
console.log(newstring);
```

ahora bien como vemos `map` es igual a un bucle `for` que intera sobre cada elemento del arreglo y  el `&&` no es mas que un `shorthand` if o [operador logico](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) que evalua que no sea nada osea `false` y no nos agrege  donde solo hay espacios
ya que al hacer el `split(' ')` tomara en cuenta los espacios continuos diviendolo como posiciones del `arreglo`  :
ejemplo:

```js
    // hacemos un bucle for
 for(let x of "cada palabra sera sustituida por    el emoji de pizza".split(' ')){
    // validamos si es true o false
    console.log(Boolean(x))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que en ese caso **map()** en esa sentencia se usa de esta forma:

```
const map = Array.prototype.map
```

Es un arreglo de tipo **String**, y ya que hace una operación para cada valor de un Array realiza un **return** de lo siguiente: `object.value`, es decir, `[caracter1,caracter2,caracter3,caracter4,...]`